# How can i find the correct link for mapping a sharepoint as a network drive?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Kbt.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0N0u.jpg)

I tried different ways to input my location link.
I have tried these: 
https://securitasgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/HKFS/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

https://securitasgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/HKFS/Shared%20Documents

ftps://securitasgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/HKFS/Shared%20Documents

what is the valid link for me to map it? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Open the SharePoint library in the Explorer View with IE Browser:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]